# Complex Gaussian integral

Tags: integration, complex-integration, gaussian-integral, quantum-field-theory

I want to calculate this integral $$I=\int \prod\limits_{i=1}^N{d \bar z_{i}dz_{i}\exp[\sum_{i,j=1}^N \bar z_{i}M_{ij}z_{j}+\sum_{i=1}^N(\bar z_{i}f_{i}+\bar g_{i}z_{i}})],$$ where $z_{i}$ are complex variables, $g_{i}$ and $f_{i}$ are complex numbers.

One can calculate this integral in case $f=g$, by simple transformation $z′=z−M−1gz′=z−M−1g$.

But I can't find convenient transformation in case of $I$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found in [Condensed Matter Field Theory by Altland and Simons](https://www.amazon.ca/Condensed-Matter-Theory-Alexander-Altland/dp/0521769752) (3rd chapter, eq 3.18) which you can also find [here](http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/~alberto/apuntes/altland.pdf) for free. However in that book the derivation is just outlined and since my edition of the book also contains a typo in the outline, I will go through it.

You can recast your integral to look like this:

$I=\int d(v^{\dagger},v) exp^{-v^{\dagger}Av + w^{\dagger}v +v^{\dagger} w'}$

where $v$ is the complex vector conataining your variables $z_i$, A is the matrix containing your $M_{ij}$ and the integration measure is a shorthand for "integrating the Real and Imaginary parts of each variable seperatly over all $\mathbb{C}$ ".It can be easily seen that this integration measure is the same as teh one you had by writting yours as $d(x+iy)d(x+iy)^{*}$ and treating $x$ and $y$ as independent variables.(I tried to keep the same notation and names of quantities as my reference in case you want to give it a look after all)

From here you can employ the change of variables (this is where the typo occurs in the book):

$v=u+A^{-1}w'$

$v^{\dagger}=u^{\dagger}+w^{\dagger}{A^{-1}}^{\dagger}=u^{\dagger}+w^{\dagger}A^{-1}$

A couple of comments for that change of variables:

1. Since you are integrating over all different values of $Re\{z_i\}$ and $Im\{z_i\}$ you can treat them as independent variables. Equivalently you can treat 
   $v$ and $v^{\dagger}$ as independent variables (and change them thusly).
2. I am assuming  $A$ is a Hermitian matrix and so ${A^{-1}}^{\dagger}=A^{-1}$. I have yet to find the proof for the general case (According to Altland and Simons, it exists somewhere in the literture)

Making the change of variables you get:

$-v^{\dagger}Av + w^{\dagger}v + v^{\dagger}w'= -u^{\dagger}Au +w^{\dagger}A^{-1}w'$

which turns the integral into

$I=\int d(u^{\dagger},u) e^{-u^{\dagger}Au + w^{\dagger}A^{-1} w'}=(\int d(u^{\dagger},u) e^{-u^{\dagger}Au} )e^{w^{\dagger}A^{-1} w'} = \pi ^N detA^{-1}e^{w^{\dagger}A^{-1} w'}$

The last step can be also found in the book I referenced and essentially it utilizes the fact that there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A=U^{\dagger}D_A U$, where $D_A$ is the Diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$.Making that substitution into your integral you will end up with a product of $2N$ real $1-D$ Gaussian integrals that will give you the $(\sqrt{\pi})^{2N} detA^{-1}=\pi ^N detA^{-1}$ factor.